# AngularJS cannot recognize Factory

Tags: angularjs, factory

I am having a difficult time understanding why the Controller cannot see my factory. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

My Controller:

```
myApp.controller('SNFController', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', '$location', 'foundSnfs',
function($scope, $http, $routeParams, $location, foundSnfs) { 
    $scope.snfs = null; 
    $scope.chosensnf = []; 
    $scope.hidefilter = true; 
    $scope.getlocale = function() { 
        foundSnfs.getsnfs($scope.zip, $scope.miles).then(function(res){ 
        $scope.snfs = res; 
    })
}])
```

My Factory:

```
myApp.factory('foundSnfs', function($http) { 
    var foundSnfs = {}; 
    foundSnfs.getsnfs = function (vz, vm){ 
        var g = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 
        g.geocode( { 'address': vz}, function(results, status) { 
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) { 
                var la = results[0].geometry.location.lat(); 
                var lo = results[0].geometry.location.lng(); 
                var cl = new google.maps.LatLng(la, lo); 
                var dm = vm * 1609.34; // distance in miles from meters 
                var url = 'http://data.medicare.gov/resource/hq9i-23gr.json?$where=within_circle(location,'+la+','+lo+','+dm+')&$ORDER=overall_rating DESC'; 
                return $http.get(url);
            }
        })
    }
});
```

I have 2 input fields, one with a Zip Code and another with a mileage range.  When the user clicks the button, $scope.locale is to pass the zip and miles to the factory which then processes the geolocation and then obtains the listing of nursing homes from Medicare.

Thank you.

Comment: How do you know it's not working?

Comment: I'd say the main problem is because your factory function isn't returning a promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the main problem I see is that `g.geocode` is asynchronous so you'll need to create a deferred object and return the promise. Here's an example...

```
myApp.factory('foundSnfs', function($q, $http) { 
    var foundSnfs = {}; 
    foundSnfs.getsnfs = function (vz, vm){
        var deferred = $q.defer(); 
        var g = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 
        g.geocode( { 'address': vz}, function(results, status) { 
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) { 
                var la = results[0].geometry.location.lat(); 
                var lo = results[0].geometry.location.lng(); 
                var cl = new google.maps.LatLng(la, lo); 
                var dm = vm * 1609.34; // distance in miles from meters 
                var url = 'http://data.medicare.gov/resource/hq9i-23gr.json?$where=within_circle(location,'+la+','+lo+','+dm+')&$ORDER=overall_rating DESC';

                // you can resolve a deferred object with another promise
                // which will resolve or reject appropriately.
                deferred.resolve($http.get(url));
            } else {
                deferred.reject(status);
            }
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    }

    return foundSnfs; // as eugene pointed out, you missed this
});
```

Here's an example of how you can resolve or reject deferred objects with further promises (like `$http`)

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/faxx3uue/2/)</kbd>

Comment: That was it!  I had been hung up on the factory being undefined error message.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

AngularJs factory expects a return value. [Factory](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers)

```
myApp.factory('foundSnfs', function($http) { 
var foundSnfs = {}; 
foundSnfs.getsnfs = function (vz, vm){ 
    var g = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 
    g.geocode( { 'address': vz}, function(results, status) { 
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) { 
            var la = results[0].geometry.location.lat(); 
            var lo = results[0].geometry.location.lng(); 
            var cl = new google.maps.LatLng(la, lo); 
            var dm = vm * 1609.34; // distance in miles from meters 
            var url = 'http://data.medicare.gov/resource/hq9i-23gr.json?$where=within_circle(location,'+la+','+lo+','+dm+')&$ORDER=overall_rating DESC'; 
            return $http.get(url);
        }
    })
}
// factory needs to return
return foundSnfs; 
});
```

Besides that, if `g.geocode` is async, you might want to use [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Comment: Ah, great catch! I was so focused on the async geocode stuff that I totally missed the fact that the factory wasn't returning anything. +1